# How to handle SVG in SAP UI5 Semantic Rendering

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to convert my SAP UI5 Renderer code to the new version, apiVersion : 2.

I've been able to convert most of my code, but there's a code fragment having SVG in it which I'm not sure how to convert. At the moment, the entire fragment is handled using the "write" method.

I have tried to convert the generic "write" method into a series of openStart("svg"), attr("xmlns", ..) statements, but I'm not sure how to handle statements like write("<path d='...' class='") and so on.

Is there any documentation/blogs/information about how I can handle SVG in the new SAP UI5 Renderer, apiVersion : 2?

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Thanks & Best Regards,
Shameek

Comment: Added your question to my documentation enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/issues/17